# How to squash all commits except the n most recent?

Tags: git, commit, rebase, squash

I see you can do `git rebase -i HEAD~3` to handle the latest 3 commits. Is there a way to simply squash every commit before, say, the latest 3 commits without manually going through all the commits and specifying `squash`?

For context, I created a branch (testBranch) off a branch (originalBranch). I made a bunch of commits, and now I want to merge this branch to the master branch. The problem is, I have all the commits from originalBranch.
I've even tried rebasing by doing `git rebase -i HEAD~70` (yes, there were a lot of commits in originalBranch), and editing the file as so:

```
r 14133a8 first commit message in originalBranch
s 3cb3a90 message2
s ea61cc4 message3
# ... etc
#commits from testBranch. These should remain after rebase
p a62bff7 first commit message in testBranch
p 4364e1f last commit message in testBranch
```

I though everything from originalBranch would squash into one message, but I get file conflicts when I do this. How can I simply squash every commit from originalBranch into 1 commit message while keeping the commit messages from testBranch, without file conflicts?

Answer (score 0):

Well... you can squash rather easily like this.

```
git checkout --detach originalBranch
# set branch pointer at the point where originalBranch and master diverged
git reset --soft $( git merge-base HEAD master ) # all changes are ready to be committed
git commit -m "Squashed originalBranch"
# now we replicate your branch on top of it
git cherry-pick originalBranch..testBranch # replicated all changes on top of squashed revision
# now you can consider moving your branch if you like the result
git branch -f testBranch
git checkout testBranch
```

But do you really need to do that? That's not elegant **at all**. If you don't *depend* on originalBranch and you only want to move to the top of master:

```
git rebase --onto master originalBranch testBranch
```

That will move the revisions that are from testBranch *that are not in originalBranch* on top of master.

Answer (score -1):

This is what filter-branch is for.

```
git replace --graft HEAD~3
git filter-branch --all
```

is the meat of it, every ref that traces back to `HEAD~3` will get a new history tracing back to the newly-amnesiac replacement commit.  See the filter-branch docs, you might want to rewrite tag names and such.  To back out of a filter-branch whose results you don't like, `git fetch . +refs/original/*:*`; to clean up after a filter-branch whose results you're sure you want to keep, `git filter-branch -f --setup exit`.

Comment: hmm, doesn't seem to work. `git filter-branch --all` returns usage message. Will read more into docs

Comment: Yeah, you can ignore that message.  Let the (five second?) timeout pass or do `export FILTER_BRANCH_SQUELCH_WARNING=1`.